# add a commenting feature to my detailViewController

Tags: ios, comments, tableview

i'm fairly new to iOS development, i'm trying to add a commenting feature to my detailViewController but im haveing no luck i thought if i added a test area like so:

```
UITextView  *txt = [[UITextView  alloc]init];

//set frame

//add on view

[self.view addSubView:txt];

[txt release];
```

it would work but nope, its for image people upload and you know how it goes if someone taps the image in the tableview it navigates to the detailViewController and it does that and shows the image and the name of it the next couple of steps involve, number of likes, number of views but thats for later date but you get my drift so i'm trying to add a commenting feature to my detailViewController what am i not correctly what are the steps?

Comment: I don't understand what is not working

Comment: i dont know how to add a commenting feature i just tried to place in a text area in a cell but its not the right way to set up a commenting feature so i was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set up the commenting feature in ios like you would see in a detailViewController